# Elementos diferentes entre dos tablas

Tags: sql, postgresql, ms-access

Necesito comparar dos tablas, ambas tienen la misma estructura, digamos

```
+-----------+----------+-----------+
|  Tabla 1  | Relación |  Tabla 2  |
+===========+==========+===========+
| Columna A | <------> | Columna A |
+-----------+----------+-----------+
| Columna B | <------> | Columna B |
+-----------+----------+-----------+
| Columna C |          | Columna C |
+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

El índice en ambas tablas está formado por las columnas `A` y `B` que uso para relacionarlas.

```
SELECT 
  a.columnaA, a.columnaB, a.columnaC, 
  b.columnaA, b.columnaB, b.columnaC
FROM TABLA1 a
LEFT JOIN TABLA2 b
  ON a.columnaA=b.columnaA AND b.columnaB=b.columnaB;
```

Si hago una consulta simple, relacionando ambas tablas, pero con las consultas `JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN` y `RIGHT JOIN` no obtengo los resultados esperados.

Dejo un Fiddle que ilustra mi problema: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rs1BonMg5BYzp2pJskAEDW/1

La salida que espero es algo como esto:

```
| columnaA | columnaB | columnaC | columnaA | columnaB | columnaC |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 1        | 1        | 10       | 1        | 1        | 10       |
| 1        | 2        | 20       | 1        | 2        | 20       |
| 1        | 3        | 30       |          |          |          |
|          |          |          | 1        | 4        | 70       |
| 2        | 1        | 40       | 2        | 1        | 40       |
| 2        | 2        | 50       | 2        | 1        | 40       |
| 2        | 3        | 60       |          |          |          |
|          |          |          | 2        | 4        | 80       |
```

Espero que el SQL sea genérico, aunque prefiero PostgreSQL y si no, MS Access.

Comment: Como utilizas de nexo los campos A y B de ambas tablas, solo puedes especificar que te muestre todos los de Tabla1 o todos los de Tabla2, pero no puedes decirle *todos de todos*. Quizás deberías probar con una consulta UNION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras simular los datos con el fiddler, yo he obtenido esto, a ver si te puede servir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código SQL de mi consulta:

```
SELECT Tabla1.ColumnaA, Tabla1.ColumnaB, Tabla1.ColumnaC, Tabla2.ColumnaA, Tabla2.ColumnaB, Tabla2.ColumnaC
FROM Tabla1 RIGHT JOIN Tabla2 ON (Tabla1.ColumnaB = Tabla2.ColumnaB) AND (Tabla1.ColumnaA = Tabla2.ColumnaA)
UNION
SELECT Tabla1.ColumnaA, Tabla1.ColumnaB, Tabla1.ColumnaC, Tabla2.ColumnaA, Tabla2.ColumnaB, Tabla2.ColumnaC
FROM Tabla1 LEFT JOIN Tabla2 ON (Tabla1.ColumnaB = Tabla2.ColumnaB) AND (Tabla1.ColumnaA = Tabla2.ColumnaA);
```

Comment: Eso es exactamente lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias.